# Pandas DataFrame returns NaN values when indexing

Tags: pandas, indexing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLukV.png)I want to construct a dataframe from a column A with column B as index. At the moment i use pd.DataFrame(A, index= B) all values of column A are turned into NaN. The weird thing is that when i do pd.DataFrame(A) then seperately set the index to B, i get the result expected. Any ideas why this is happening ?

attached a screenshot:

What i tested: Seperate the DataFrame creation into 2 steps and it works as expected

Comment: Pandas does intrinsic index alignment, if your A has index and B is different then you will get nan.  Remove the indexes from A.  `pd.DataFrame(A.to_numpy(), index=B)`   Make A a numpy array without indexes.

Comment: can you post some code so that we can test?

Comment: while solving the issues it really helps if you try to go through reference docs, in this case [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and here is the [user-guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/dsintro.html#basics-dataframe) for the same.

Comment: here is the code: A=df["thick"]
B=df["Name"]
C=pd.DataFrame(A, index=B)
I get C dataframe with NAN values in column B

Comment: so to summarize : i want to create dataframe C from 2 series A & B. A & B are extracted from another dataframe constructed from csv file.  If i do pd.DataFrame(A, index=B) i get NaN values in column B. If i do C=  pd.DataFrame(A) and then set index to B (pd.set_index(B)) i got the expected result

Comment: @Scott Boston can you explain the meaning of inrinsic index alignment ? thanks

Comment: @Ret3i https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#dsintro.  Basically. if you have two dataframes nearly all pandas operations will be done between elements in a both dataframes with identical indexing (both row and column).  IE.. when you add Dataframes together column A, index row 1 in dataframe one will add to column A, index row 1 in dataframe two no matter what the sorting of either dataframe.